# SQL Max on Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stuck at a very simple t-sql query. Please help !

Following is my result set :

```
Percentage---FirstName---SessionId

34-----------ABC---------222
67-----------ABC---------333
11-----------ABC---------444
83-----------XYZ---------555
23-----------XYZ---------666
64-----------XYZ---------777
```

From above, I want records of each user with maximum percentage e.g.

```
Percentage---FirstName---SessionId
67-----------ABC---------333
83-----------XYZ---------555
```

I can't seem to do that and I'm in hurry. Please help at the earliest. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What SessionId you need in result? Any? Also what sql you use ? MS, My?

Comment: To add to the above, I already have SUM and GroupBy with the original query. I want a way to introduce a sub query or so that the original resultset remains the same with same number of columns. Thanks.

Comment: @Bugai13: "I'm stuck at a very simple t-sql query. Please help !" --- so obviously it is sql server

Comment: @ Bugai13 : As zerkms has replied its MS SQL. I don't want to filter on SessionId but on max percentage. Hope that helps, and Thanks for your replies guys !

Comment: @Bugai13: for what? I already gave my better one ;-)

Answer (score 8):

```
  SELECT MAX(Percentage) AS Percentage,
         FirstName
    FROM mytbl
GROUP BY FirstName
```

Or if you need session id:

```
    SELECT mytbl.*
      FROM mytbl
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Percentage) AS Percentage,
                   FirstName
              FROM mytbl
          GROUP BY FirstName) x ON x.Percentage = mytbl.Percentage
                               AND x.FirstName = mytbl.FirstName
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `MAX(SessionId)`. The OP asked for "... records of each user with maximum percentage"

Comment: @Tony: you missed the answer? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: Either I'm going mad, commented on the wrong answer or you edited yours :)

Comment: @Tony: yes, I wrote max session id in the first version but it lived for about several seconds before I removed that line ;-) You must be caught that moment ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: +1, only I would probably replaced `*` with `mytbl.*` (I guess there's no need to return those extra columns from the subselect.)

Answer (score 6):

If you need to deal with ties, then you might want to use the windowing functions (assuming you're on SQL Server 2005 or later):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT mytbl.*,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName ORDER BY Percentage desc) as rn) t
WHERE
    t.rn = 1
```

So if there are two rows with the same percentage, they'll both be returned. If you only want one result, then you can add additional "tie-breaker" columns to the `ORDER BY` clause, or switch from [`RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) to [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Comment: +1 Much simpler than what I garbled together. The ranking functions are still not second nature to me.

Comment: It seems better, only the OP should take into account the fact that it's for SQL Server 2005+.

Comment: @Andriy M - thanks, couldn't remember which version they were introduced with.

Comment: Btw, I think you're missing a `FROM` at the end of your sub-select.  And your outer select will return the Windowing value as well.